# WPF/C# - ListBox example whats the ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, msdn

I want to understand the example from msdn
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx#defining_simple_datatemplate).

XAML Code:

```
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyTodoList}}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Priority}"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

The Data in the Text Blocks are Properties from an Object, is this right?
The Object is in the List (?) myTodoList in the code behind file?

```
protected ObservableCollection<TODO> _myTodoList= new ObservableCollection<TODO>();
public ObservableCollection<TODO> MyTodoList
{
    get { return _myTodoList; }
}
```

Add TODO's

```
TODO t1 = new TODO();
t1.TaskName = "TaskName1";
t1.Description = "Description1";
t1.Priority = "Priority1";
_myTodoList.Add(t1);

TODO t2 = new TODO();
t2.TaskName = "TaskName2";
t2.Description = "Description2";
t2.Priority = "Priority2";
_myTodoList.Add(t2);
```

My Test TODO Class:

```
public class TODO
{
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
}
```

But the code throws an exception... 
[image]

whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the StaticResource:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SDKSample"
        ...
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Tasks x:Key="MyTodoList"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

From the SDKSample:

```
public class Tasks : ObservableCollection<Task>
{
    public Tasks(): base()
    {
        Add(new Task("Groceries", "Pick up Groceries and Detergent", 2, TaskType.Home));
        Add(new Task("Laundry", "Do my Laundry", 2, TaskType.Home));
        Add(new Task("Email", "Email clients", 1, TaskType.Work));
        Add(new Task("Clean", "Clean my office", 3, TaskType.Work));
        Add(new Task("Dinner", "Get ready for family reunion", 1, TaskType.Home));
        Add(new Task("Proposals", "Review new budget proposals", 2, TaskType.Work));
    }
}
```

Comment: what ist Task (<local:Tasks>)?`

Comment: In the example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx#DataTemplating_Basic) it is the list with your Task objects.

Comment: See my edit and take a look at this [sample project](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7748).

Comment: `<local:Tasks x:Key="MyTodoList"/>` Why do I have enter a class name here? Is there a way to specify a method here?

Comment: This is what Jeetendra.Sharma suggested in his answer. See [ObjectDataProvider.MethodName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.methodname.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

In your code behind file, in the contructor put the following:

```
this.DataContext = this.MyTodoList;
```

Then change your ListBox:

```
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have do define the datacontext on the top of this

`<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type m:yourvmtype}" x:Key="MyTodoList" MethodName="GetStrings"/>
</StackPanel.Resources>`